# NiFi: how to store maxTimestamp when using ListFile/GetFile processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

i am using MiNiFi 0.3 and NiFi 1.5 version.

we have a requirement to pull the data(csv) from 'A' folder using MiNiFi and send to NiFi running in linux.

for instance, if file is arriving with 10 records on 1 am. we need to move(not copy) file from 'A' folder to NiFi hub.
After 10 minutes (1.10 am), the appended file will be arriving with the older 10 records and new 10 records. so, totally it will contain 20 records.

we need to send only the new 10 records to the NiFi hub.

i tried ListFile -> FetchFile, but since we need to move the data. this does not work.
then i tried with GetFile processor, but it captures the whole 20 records.

is there any way to achieve the scenario.

thanks in advance.

Comment: for example you could store it in file  `data.csv` -> `data.csv.timestamp`

Comment: it would be helpful if you explain in detail. which processor and where data.csv should be present?

Comment: csv is just a text file. to filter out rows - you have to parse it and use QueryRecord to remove unnecessary rows. there should be something unique in one of the fields (timestamp for example) that will be used for filtering. and store the last value of this unique field into a separate file instead of incoming file but with some suffix.

Comment: how to parse and extract the maximum datetime from csv. i used ExtractText processor, but could not find the matching regular expression.

Comment: how to read the data.csv file after when i get the original data from ListFile processor?

Answer (score 1):

Using `FetchFile`, you can configure it using property `Completion Strategy` to `Move File` or even `Delete File`(and then you can `PutFile` it whenever you like).

Comment: Completion Strategy property with Move value able to move the file to the destination location. i wanted to achieve for the same file arriving with appended new records. this time, i want to move only the new records alone. how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe fetching the file and waiting a bit and fetching it again until all the records are available?

Comment: our requirement is, the file will have updated records coming every 10 minutes. And we need to process as soon as the new appended data is available.

Comment: what about the same process but then -> `EvaluateJsonPath` with `$.length()` property(to extract number of records) -> `RouteOnAttrribute`(to check how many records are there) and that way decide if to move or not move the file yet

Comment: i have my source file as csv.